# Reference Request: Left-Invariant Metrics on Lie Group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for suggestions on getting started with reading about left-invariant metrics on Lie groups. I'm especially interested in examples of left-invariant metrics on the general linear group $\mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$. It would be really nice if I could find explicit calculations for curvatures, Ricci tensors, that sort of thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't every inner product on the Lie algebra induce a left invariant metric? This follows from the fact that left multiplication induces a left invariant framing.